# How to use Vue Component on custom formatter in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tabulator, formatter

newbie in vuejs.

I'm trying to use [tabulator](http://tabulator.info) data-table for data and used [Custom Formatters](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/format#format-custom). But unable to return Vue component.

How to return Vue component on custom formatter Vue3?

```
<script>
import BaseLink from "@/components/BaseLink.vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      switch1: false,
      columns: [
        {
          rowHandle: true,
          formatter: "handle",
          headerSort: false,
          frozen: true,
          width: 30,
          minWidth: 30,
        },
        { title: "ID", field: "id", editor: "input" },
        { title: "Name", field: "name" },
        { title: "Email", field: "email" },
        {
          title: "Status",
          field: "status",
          formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
            //cell - the cell component
            //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
            //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered
            return `<v-switch v-model="switch1" />`;
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Action",
          field: "id",
          formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
            //cell - the cell component
            //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
            //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered
            return `<BaseLink to="/members/${cell.getValue()}/details">Details</BaseLink>`;
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: This is not possible. Tabulator's custom formatters can only return strings.

Comment: @tony19 are you certain? How are custom formatters different from the builtin ones that allow you to do this. https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Format/defaults/formatters/star.js

Comment: @Manuel No, I'm not certain of anything. :) Given that link, it's possible for formatter to return HTML elements as well as strings, but the OP is trying to tie in Vue components that are bound to local component props. That might only be feasible within `<script setup>`.